# Do we always have to run Bellman-Ford N-1 times?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, graph-traversal, bellman-ford

This is more a theoretical question because I can see this question being asked in an exam.
Assuming we have a directed graph G(V,E) with |V| = 10 and we want to know the shortest path from S to all other 9 vertices. Assuming we know that the longest path from S has length 5 do we still have to run Bellman-Ford 9 times or can we run it 5 times and conclude that we have found the shortest path ?

When trying it on an example it worked but it could also just be luck and there might me some edgecase I am missing.

Comment: Already answered at https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50558

Comment: @AbhinavMathur The question asked on the other site is not the same exactly. From the detailed accepted answer, we can conclude the answer to the question here, but it is not immediate in my opinion.

Comment: According to https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html#the-proof-of-the-algorithm, you are correct: "For any vertex  `a`  let us denote the  `k` number of edges in the shortest path to it (if there are several such paths, you can take any). According to this statement, the algorithm guarantees that after  `k`th  phase the shortest path for vertex  `a`  will be found."

Comment: The proof is simple: Consider a shortest path with `k` edges `a0, a1, ..., ak`. On the first iteration, the edge `a0 -> a1` is checked, so the distance from `a0` to `a1` is calculated correctly. On iteration 2, the edge `a1 -> a2` is checked, so the distance from `a0` to `a2` must be correct after iteration 2. It is easy to see that within `k` iterations, the distance from `a0` to `ak` must be fully calculated. Again, note the "within": you might not even need `k` iterations if the order in which you check edges is lucky.